# How do I reset a knockout select control to the optionCaption selection?

Tags: knockout.js

I have tried `selectBox(0)` but that just clears the dropdown. I have also tried `selectBox(null)` and `selectBox(undefined)`, the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange, `select(undefined)` should work. Take a look at this example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kau0xhgy/1/

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I was setting the array and not the selectedValue.

Comment: it happens with everybody